# Weird behavior of a RecyclerView within CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm having some trouble with a partly hidden `RecyclerView` on the small devices below 5.5" (Nexus, A3, etc...)

Once the feed's loaded, and added to the adapter items, all the children of the `CoordinatorLayout` moved up.

You can see the demo **[here](https://youtu.be/Ij6KxPXAxOE)**

Here's the hierarchy of the view:

```
CoordinatorLayout
    AppBarLayout
        LiveCollapsingToolbarLayout
    CardView
        ConstraintLayout
    SmoothRecyclerView
```

And here the main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/live_main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/home_header_height_reduced"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.radiofrance.radio.francebleu.android.view.toolbar.LiveCollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/live_collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentScrim="@color/bleu_primary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:importantForAccessibility="noHideDescendants"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/live_weather_cover"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                <com.radiofrance.radio.francebleu.android.fonts.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/live_date"
                    style="@style/HomeDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/live_ephemeris"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6"
                    tools:text="@tools:sample/date/day_of_week" />

                <com.radiofrance.radio.francebleu.android.fonts.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/live_ephemeris"
                    style="@style/HomeEphemeride"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/live_weather"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/live_date"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
                    tools:text="St Guy" />

                <com.radiofrance.radio.francebleu.android.fonts.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/live_weather"
                    style="@style/HomeTemperature"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/live_ephemeris"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.7"
                    tools:text="14°" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                <com.radiofrance.radio.francebleu.android.fonts.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/live_toolbar_title"
                    style="@style/TextHomeToolbarTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        </com.radiofrance.radio.francebleu.android.view.toolbar.LiveCollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/live_card_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/home_live_card_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/home_live_card_horizontal_margin"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="48dp"
        app:cardElevation="3.8dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="@bool/card_overlap"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/live_card_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:importantForAccessibility="yes">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/live_card_cover"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,16:9"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@color/translucent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/live_card_cover"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/live_card_cover"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/live_card_cover"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/live_card_cover" />

            <com.radiofrance.radio.francebleu.android.fonts.FontTextView
                style="@style/TextHomeLiveStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:text="@string/home_live_status"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <com.radiofrance.radio.francebleu.android.fonts.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/live_card_player_debug"
                style="@style/TextHomeLiveStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="Player debug" />

            <com.radiofrance.radio.francebleu.android.fonts.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/live_card_title"
                style="@style/TextHomeLiveTitle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="3"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/live_card_cover"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/live_card_player"
                tools:text="Live de France Bleu" />

            <com.radiofrance.radio.francebleu.android.view.progress.ProgressCircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/live_card_player"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/home_play_button_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/home_play_button_size"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/live_card_cover"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:pciv_background="@drawable/bg_play_dark"
                app:pciv_padding="12dp"
                app:pciv_progressBackground="@drawable/bg_play_progress_dark"
                app:pciv_progressColor="@color/bleu_primary"
                app:pciv_src="@drawable/eavd_vd_play" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/live_card_cover_text"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/live_card_cover">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/HomeLiveTxt"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:lines="2"
                    android:text="@string/home_call_description" />

                <com.radiofrance.radio.francebleu.android.fonts.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/live_card_call"
                    style="@style/TextRobotoBold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/home_call_action"
                    android:text="@string/home_call_action"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/bleu_accent" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <com.radiofrance.radio.francebleu.android.view.error.GenericErrorView
                android:id="@+id/live_card_error"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <com.radiofrance.radio.francebleu.android.view.scroll.SmoothRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/live_feed_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="48dp"
        android:accessibilityTraversalAfter="@id/live_card_layout"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <include layout="@layout/card_see_new_actualities" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[Update]
 It seems the problem comes from the horizontal recyclerview that is in `live_feed_recyclerview` as a `ViewHolder`

Comment: Could you pelase post your layout file.

Comment: Just udpdated @RobinVinzenz ;) 
Thanks for ur help